# Function that uses if/else statement

Tags: javascript, string, function, if-statement

I have created a function that will print all numbers between 1-24. If the number is dividable by 3, it will print Fizz, if dividable by 5, it will print Buzz.

If start > stop, I want to add an error message. How can I do that? I tried with alert but that did not work out at all.

2) When I print the function with start= 2 and stop=24 the first value that shows up is "undefined". Why is that?

By using .substr(1) I want to remove the first comma to the left.

```
function fizzBuzz(start, stop) {
  if (start >= stop)
 var returnString;
 for(var i= start; i <= stop; i++) {
    returnString += ",";
    if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0)
      returnString += "FizzBuzz";
    else if (i % 3 === 0)
        returnString += "Fizz";
   else if (i % 5 === 0)
        returnString += "Buzz";
    else
        returnString += i;
}
 return returnString;
}
var result = fizzBuzz(2, 24).substr(1);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `if (start >= stop)` means start must be > or = to stop, and you're saying that `start = 2` and `stop = 24`, so start < stop

Comment: You can avoid a leading comma in the first place by initializing `returnString` to an empty string, then using `if (returnString.length>0) returnString += ",";`

Comment: There are several ways to avoid the leading comma. Unless in other uses of that function you need the leading comma, about the worst way to do it is by modifying the result of the function. Do it in the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to show error message if `start >= stop`, it can be done using `alert`. You are getting undefined for the first time because `returnString` variable didn't declare anywhere.

So try something like this. It would solve your problem

```
function fizzBuzz(start, stop) {
    var returnString = '';
    if (start >= stop) {
        alert('stop must be greater than start');
        return;
    }
    for (var i = start; i <= stop; i++) {
        returnString += ",";
        if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) 
            returnString += "FizzBuzz";
        else if (i % 3 === 0) 
            returnString += "Fizz";
        else if (i % 5 === 0) 
            returnString += "Buzz";
        else returnString += i;
    }
    return returnString;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sachinyadav/80rcjx9v/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to put validation in if clause

```
if (start >= stop)
{
   return "start must be less than stop";
}
```

And you need to initialize `returnString` with empty string first

```
var returnString = "";
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do this .

```
function fizzBuzz(start, stop) {
  if (start >= stop){
     throw "start must be less than stop";
  }
 var returnString = "";
  ...
  ...
  ...
 return returnString;
}
var result = fizzBuzz(2, 24).substr(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

For the error mressage use [`throw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw)

```
function fizzBuzz(start, stop) {
  if (start >= stop){
     throw "start must be less than stop";
  }
  ....
```

This requires you catch the error if you want to display info to the user

```
try{
    var result = fizzBuzz(72, 24).substr(1);
    alert(result);
}catch(e){
    alert(e); // alerts "start must be less than stop"
}
```

The second question is because `resultString` starts life as `undefined` and when you concatenate a string to undefined you get the string "UndefinedYOURSTRINGHERE". Define `returnString` as an empty string.

```
 var returnString = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

The first value shows up is undefined because that's how you declared it:

```
if (start >= stop)
 var returnString;
```

Notice you don't have an opening bracket, so you basically just declare that variable. Even if you don't declare it, it will still be undefined later on when you do:

`returnString += ",";`

Since it always starts as `undefined`.

You can move that line to the end, and also you can add an alert at the first `if` check and return if `start > stop`:

```
function fizzBuzz(start, stop) {
    if (start >= stop) {
        alert('This is wrong');
        return;
    }


  returnString = "";
  for(var i= start; i <= stop; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0)
      returnString += "FizzBuzz";
    else if (i % 3 === 0)
        returnString += "Fizz";
   else if (i % 5 === 0)
        returnString += "Buzz";
    else
        returnString += i;

    returnString += ",";
}

 return returnString;
}
var res = fizzBuzz(2, 24);
var result = res.substring(0, res.length - 1);;
console.log(result);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qdrvywv3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a throw statement for the error:

```
if (start >= stop){
    throw "first integer must be less than 2nd integer"
}
```

You must also declare returnString with an initial value:

```
 var returnString = "";
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is here,

```
if (start >= stop) 
var returnString;
```

There is no need for if statement here but still if you need you can do this,

```
  function fizzBuzz(start, stop) { if (start >= stop){
     var returnString;
 for(var i= start; i <= stop; i++) { returnString += ","; 
if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) returnString += "FizzBuzz"; 
else if (i % 3 === 0) returnString += "Fizz"; else if (i % 5 === 0) returnString += "Buzz";
 else returnString += i; }
 return returnString;
 }
    }
     var result = fizzBuzz(2, 24).substr(1);
```